# Implementing redirect url feature in the ItemResolver pipeline

Tags: pipelines, redirect

I'm working on a redirect url feature and have added a pipeline processor after the ItemResolver.

However the value of **HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.LocalPath** equals **"/layouts/system/VisitorIdentificationCSS.aspx"** rather than the value typed in the address bar. If I patch before the ItemResolver it works.

If I disable `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()` from my view the pipeline is never hit for as long as it's after ItemResolver.

Any idea what this relates to? I'm not sure if it relates to the license not including xDB

```
public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args) 
{ 
    if (args.Context.Request.Url.OriginalString.ToLower().Contains(‌​"/sitecore")) 
        return; 

    if (Sitecore.Context.Item == null) 
        var path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.LocalPath;

}
```

Comment: Can you share code of your processor?

Comment: I've stripped it right down to something very simple and the variable 'path' is the problematic one. Pretty odd one this:

        `public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)  
        {  
            if   (args.Context.Request.Url.OriginalString.ToLower().Contains("/sitecore"))
                return;  
            if (Sitecore.Context.Item == null)  
                var path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.LocalPath;  
        }`

Answer (score 5):

Problem is with:

```
if (Sitecore.Context.Item == null)
```

in your code.

After `ItemResolver` is executed, that will be never null for Sitecore items.

That's why you only see this hit for `VisitorIdentification`.

If you want your code to be executed when Sitecore "page" is loaded, change your code to

```
if (Sitecore.Context.Item != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just an update, I did want to use _context.item == null_ because I only want to be able to setup redirects for items that don't already exist in Sitecore. Strangely enough it started working once I made a call to an item before attempting to get the LocalPath. Odd one really not sure what caused it to return VisitorIdentification in the first pace